# Task Manager and profiler for Android Wear apps

Tags: applications, battery-life, user-interface, android-wear

I have three questions about Android wear apps.

1. Is there a way or app for closing individual apps on Android wear ? I tried [Task Manager for Android wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rocketstartups.weartaskmanager&hl=en) but it doesn't work on my LG Watch R.
2. how can I profile an individual app on Android wear (on my Watch) in terms of CPU, memory and power consumption ? For Android phones, there are apps such as power tutor, trepn etc, however, I can't find any way to do the same for a smartwatch.
3. Is there a way to adapt an android app to smartwatch in terms of display (user interface) without having access to the source code ? I want to use an android app on android wear, however, I can not see all the options due to the small display of the watch. I was wondering if there is way to deal with it such that to make the app user-interface smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been unable to find any profiling apps designed for Android smartwatches. However, its been reported that [Trepn Profiler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quicinc.trepn&hl=en) can be used with Android Wear smartwatches. Here is [a screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3X6VWjjExwc1Baa28zOHF4NVE/view) of Trepn running on the LG Watch R:

Based on the data I've seen, this smartwatch reports accurate power consumption:

- With a dim display, 252 mW of power is consumed.
- With a bright display, 671 mW is used.

It looks like the above screenshot was created using Trepn's 'Network Activity' preset.

Obviously Trepn is not ideal for this purpose, since it was never designed to run on a smartwatch. You won't be able to access important features like its Advanced mode or Settings.

Although I haven't tested them yet, I would expect all of Trepn's overlay presets to work. *Note:* To make sure you have an overlay preset, touch the icon to the right that looks like an overlay, not a list. In most cases it's the bottom icon.

- CPU Frequency
- Mobile Data Detective
- Performance Graph
- CPU Usage Monitor
- CPU Load Overlay

*Disclosure:* I work on the team that created Trepn and App Tune-up Kit.